# Превратить строку в n-массивов символов

Tags: java, массивы

Как из содержимого массива `String[] subStr;`, где `i = n` создать `n` массивов, уже заполненные содержимым из `n`.
Например `i = 3`, создать соответственно 3 новых заполненных массива. Например, есть строка:

```
Make Life Great
```

Нужно создать 3 массива:

```
{"M","a","k","e"}
{"L","i","f","e"}
{"G","r","e","a","t"}
```

```java
String str = "Make Life Great";
String[] subStr;
String delimiter = " ";
subStr = str.split(delimiter);
char[] result = subStr[i].toCharArray(); // как лучше использовать char[]?
```

Буду премного благодарен, если подскажете. Можно объяснением или блоком кода.

Comment: String str = "Make Life Great"; List<String[]> collect = Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).map(s->s.split("")).collect(Collectors.toList()); получите коллекцию нужных вам массивов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем двумерный массив символов `String[][]` из строки `String`:

```java
String str = "Make Life Great";

String[][] chars = Arrays
        // разделяем строку на массив
        // подстрок по пробельным символам
        .stream(str.split("\\s+"))
        .map(sub -> sub
                // для каждой подстроки
                // получаем массив символов
                .codePoints()
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        // получаем двумерный
        // массив символов
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(chars));
// [[M, a, k, e], [L, i, f, e], [G, r, e, a, t]]
```

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях подсказали, спасибо.

```java
String str = "Make Life Great";
List<String[]> list = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
        .map(s -> s.split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list.get(i))); // [Make][Life][Great]
}
```